# C# : no row at position

Tags: c#, data-binding

I encounter some strange issue with my code. In my table, I have 58 records and when I run it using the messagebox, I get 57 as MaxRecord which is correct assuming first record start with 0.

When I clicked on the `Last_Button` to scroll to the last record, it says

> There is no row at position 57.

Is there something wrong with my code ? Thanks.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public partial class myfunction : Form
    {
        public int CarNumber { get; set; }
        public kilnRec CurrentKilnRec { get; set; }
        public int CurrentIndex { get; set; }
        public int LastIndex { get; set; }
        public int MaxIndex { get; set; }
        public string CarNo { get; set; }

        public myfunction()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myfunction_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                LoadDB();
                ResetButton();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void myfunction_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LastIndex = 0;
        }

        public OleDbConnection DBConnection { get; set; }
        public DataTable mytableTable { get; set; }

        private void LoadDB()
        {
            DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(DbManager.DbConnectionString);
            DBConnection.Open();
            var oleDBCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE rec_no >= -9 AND rec_no <= 48 ORDER BY rec_no", DBConnection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };
            var oleDBDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleDBCmd);
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            oleDBDataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
            mytableTable = dataset.Tables[0];
            MaxIndex = dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(MaxIndex));
            CurrentIndex = LastIndex;
            CurrentKilnRec = new kilnRec();
            SetRecord();
        }

        private void SetRecord()
        {
            var CurrentRow = mytableTable.Rows[CurrentIndex];
            this.tbCarPos.Text = Convert.ToString(CurrentRow["rec_no"]);
            this.tbCarNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(CurrentRow["carno"]);
            this.tbProdName.Text = Convert.ToString(CurrentRow["prodname"]);
            this.tbQuantity.Text = Convert.ToString(CurrentRow["quantity"]);
            this.tbWeight.Text = Convert.ToString(CurrentRow["weight"]);
        }

        private void ResetButton()
        {
            bt_First.Enabled = true;
            bt_Prior.Enabled = true;
            bt_Next.Enabled = true;
            bt_Last.Enabled = true;

            if (CurrentIndex == 0)
            {
                bt_First.Enabled = false;
                bt_Prior.Enabled = false;
                bt_Next.Enabled = true;
                bt_Last.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (CurrentIndex == MaxIndex)
            {
                bt_First.Enabled = true;
                bt_Prior.Enabled = true;
                bt_Next.Enabled = false;
                bt_Last.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void bt_First_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentIndex = 0;
            SetRecord();
            ResetButton();
        }

        private void bt_Prior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentIndex--;
            SetRecord();
            ResetButton();
        }

        private void bt_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentIndex++;
            SetRecord();
            ResetButton();
        }

        private void bt_Last_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentIndex = MaxIndex;
            SetRecord();
            ResetButton();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: every other button is working well?

Comment: that is normal. `MaxIndex = dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;` gives your the count. So for a 0-based collection. The last item is `Count - 1`

Comment: Ok, I thought if I have exactly 58 records in my database, my last record will be MaxIndex = 57 and first record would be MaxIndex = 0

Comment: I don't think there is a recno == 0. So your query would return 48 + 9 records.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MaxIndex is the total number of items(rows). Starting from 0, this index can go upto MaxIndex - 1.

If you have MaxIndex as 57 then your index is from 0 to 56 (that totals to 57).

So, in your code, use MaxIndex-1 to go to the last item/row and same CurrentIndex == MaxIndex-1 to enable the "first" button.